# How does polarity of "none" work in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

When looking at links, you can set the polarity as "none" (default), "+", "-", "s", "o". My question is, if you leave it as "none", does that assume "+" and if not, how do they differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System dynamics link polarity settings are *purely* cosmetic (for annotating your model) and have no bearing on what actually happens.

So this is a system dynamics theory question, not an AnyLogic question.

People like John Sterman (prominent SD guru and textbook author) don't mention 'None' as a normal usage (see [this article for example](https://thesystemsthinker.com/fine-tuning-your-causal-loop-diagrams-part-i/)), so I suspect this is a non-normative option.